# @egjs Flicking plugin for Vue. Not working adaptive

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the "[@egjs/flicking](https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/)" plugin for a Vue 2 project. I have a slider with different panel heights. I want the height of my slider to adapt to the largest size of the panels that are in the field of view.

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flicking-adaptive-q9bl3b?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `adaptive: true,`
and add for `.panel` `height: 100%;`

This should help.
[image]

Comment: I want to achieve this effect: https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/Options#adaptive. So that the height changes when a large element appears in the field of view